# error details 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body In content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length

Tags: python, discord.py

I get this error in discord.py bot what this means - error details 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length.

The fun fact is that i get this sometimes and sometimes not in the same code .

Answer (score 3):

2K is the maximum length of characters you can send. It's the default restriction in the discord. It would be due to you are sending a list or dictionary containing more than the recommended limit.

Answer (score 1):

So, even if you have Nitro and can send 4k, that doesn't extend to your tuppers? Because I just sent a pretty long RP Post in a server and got this error code. I figured that was the issue. The message sent, just from me and not my tupper. It's not a big deal, I'm just new to the whole Nitro thing and am still not sure how everything words lol

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the Question. It seems more like a comment. Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers on Stack Overflow work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29980418)